# Building Angular project using VPN

Tags: angular, vpn

I am working on an Angular project in my job's computer. Now I am accessing to that machine through a VPN with my home's computer and I am trying to make the project work in my home's computer.

The "ng serve -o" command on my job's device works ok.
However, when I try to run it on my home's computer, I am getting this error:
"The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."

In case it helps, I have accessed to the Angular project through my home's computer through the path \job_computers_name\user\angular-project. I see all the files and I got them on my Visual Studio Code, but the command line "ng serve --o" still throws that error.

I have tried changing my Angular CLI and node version to the ones I have in my job's computer, but I am getting the same error.

Would appreciate any hint on how to setup this correctly.